# RegEx Numeric with Length

Tags: regex, limit, numeric

How I can to create a Numeric Regex with decimal separator, but also limit the length

I create this:

```
^[0-9]([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]){1,10}$
```

Then 1234567890.1234567890 is valid, but is using 20(+1 -> decimal separator) characters.

How I can do to limit to 10 characters?

Valid:

```
1234567890
123456789.0
12345678.90
1234567.890
123456.7890
12345.67890
12345.67890
1234.567890
123.4567890
12.34567890
1.234567890
```

Not Valid:

```
12345678901
12345678901.
123456789.01
12345678.901
1234567.8901
123456.78901
12345.678901
12345.678901
1234.5678901
123.45678901
12.345678901
1.2345678901
.12345678901
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: honestly I would just check that it matches `/^\d+(?:\.\d*)$/` and then `s/\.//;` and check the length.

Comment: Should `.123` or `123.` be a valid match? Also, I'm guessing exponential notation is not allowed?

Comment: @LoneShepherd the best option is that you say, but is a dynamic form, the I need to controll the length too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker in my case can't be .123 or 123. valid.

Comment: Well, then my solution should work just fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{1,10}|(?!.{12})\d+\.\d+)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Start of string
(?:        # Either match...
 \d{1,10}  # an integer (up to 10 digits)
|          # or
 (?!.{12}) # (as long as the length is not 12 characters or more)
 \d+\.\d+  # a floating point number
)          # End of alternation
$          # End of string
```

Note that (as in your example) `.123` or `123.` are not valid.

Comment: +1 for using a fancy lookahead assertion to get a single regex :-)

Comment: @TimPietzker works like a charm... Thanks!!! I'll change it a little `^(?:[0-9]{1,10}|(?!.{12})[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)$` because have problem with \ character in C#

Answer (score 1):

It's more clear and maybe even faster if you don't use regex to count the length. Test it against `^\d+(?:\.\d+)$`, remove dots and take the length.

If you really need it to be one regular expression, you can use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check the format *and* the length separately:

```
^\d{1,10}$|^(?=.{11}$)\d+\.\d+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          # At the start of the string
(?:        # either
 \d{1,10}  # up to 10 digits
|          # or
 (?=       # from here
  .{11}    # 11 characters
  $        # to the end
 )         # and as well
 \d+\.\d+  # two dot-separated digit sequences
)          # 
$          #
```

Comment: thanks! This solution needs all the 10 digits. I change it to: `^\d{1,10}$|^(?=.{1,11}$)\d+\.\d+$` to admit variation from 1 to 10 digits.

Comment: Maybe I don't clarify this in my examples.